# Sporadic handshake errors with Charles SSL proxying

Tags: android, ssl, proxy, charles-proxy

I want to monitor the traffic of my android phone using Charles 3.10.2. However I am getting sporadic handshake errors, i.e., the server responds with `400 Bad Request` when doing

```
CONNECT HOSTNAME:443 HTTP/1.1
```

The following failure reason is shown when this happens:

```
SSLHandshake: Client requested protocol SSLv3 not enabled or not supported
```

The strange thing is, that some requests to the same host work while others don't.

Any ideas how to fix this? I already installed the root cert of charles on the phone. Thanks in advance for helpful answers.